# Request header value getting null in spring?

Tags: java, angular, spring-mvc

I am getting null value while accessing UID value in header.

Spring returning content of file.

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .header("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileName)
                .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                .header("UID","ug2781")
                .body(content)
```

angular accessing UID value but getting null

api

```
 getFile(url:string,uid:any):Observable<any>{
    let headers:any= {
        headers:new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'UID':uid
      }),
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'responseType':'arraybuffer' as 'json',
      'observe':'response',
    }
    return this.http.get(urls.fileurl+"?url="+url,headers)
    .pipe(map((res)=>{
      return res;
    }),catchError(err=>{
      console.log(err)
      return err;
    })
    )
    
 }
```

calling api

```
this.api.getRunFile(url,uid).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res.headers.get("UID"))  //getting null here
    },err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you share some more angular code like where you getting response object?

Comment: @Chellappanவ I have updated code please check once

Answer (score 1):

```
this.api.getRunFile(url,uid).subscribe((res)=>{
  console.log(res.headers.get("UID"))  //getting null here
},err=>{
  console.log(err)
})
```

u can try below code

```
this.api.getRunFile(url,uid).subscribe((res)=>{
  console.log(res.headers.get("uid"))
},err=>{
  console.log(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try method getAllResponseHeaders() and check key header